# Grouped UITableView and cell design problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

i've designed a UITableView in an app that i'm developing 
The view is designed in interface builder and table style is set to grouped there
But i'm facing a little problem in table design. 
As You can see in the screenshot below the first separator is bolder than normal borders and as you can note in the second screenshot the separator in the last sections doesn't appear at all.
As because there's no problem if table have only two sections and not three i'm thinking that there may be a problem in dequeuereusableCellWithIdentifier, but i can't manage to resolve the issue.
Table Cell is a subclass of UITableViewCell designed in interface builder and loaded by using this code

```
 NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GraphiDetailTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
 cell = (GraphiDetailTableCell *)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

I've checked that the cellIdentifier is the same in interface builder and in cellForRowAtIndexPath
Thanks in advance if anybody can help me facing this problem
.
[image: first screenshot]
[image: second screenshot]

Comment: is there any reason why you need to subclass UITableViewCell?, it would be far easier to just use the content view to layout your subviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. i have forget to implement the heightForRowAtIndexPath method. I've had set it only in the xib file

Answer (score 1):

Your code for create the cell in the delegate method its something like that ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (!cell) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"]autorelease];
    }


    /* your code */


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is like that. by having a "brainstorming" i've managed to solve this issue.